# What is the base framework of making a minimalist mobile game?

Tags: android, game-design, opengl-es3

I've seen plenty of minimalist games throughout the years recently like Blue Box, Loop, Colorolo and Ultraflow. Games that use simple shapes. What's not talked about is the design process of making such games, specifically with a clean, vector-like visual presentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is too broad. There are just too many different technologies which can be used to create games like that and those can be used in infinitely many development processes. There isn't one "design process of making such games". Every team has their own.

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here. You mention both [tag:game-design], the process of making decisions about how game mechanics should work, and [tag:opengl-es3], the tech you're using to draw pixels on your screen. These are not closely related. Is it game design you want help with, or rendering techniques? What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck or unsatisfied with the process you're using now? Explaining the question in the context of your own game in development is often more constructive than name-dropping existing games.

Comment: @DMGregory Its not "name-dropping." If you look at those that I've mentioned, you will see a pattern/style of using geometry as a means of pushing a game. Its also quite obvious that they use opengl for renderin, which is not the problem as Im not looking for "how-to" code. Furthermore, I only mentioned opengl-es3, because of visual results where non-opengl methods tend to appear not as crisp. I inserted game design in terms of a conceptual explanation, not as a "fix this/do my work" solution. If you haven't any idea, leave it be. Someone else may understand it better.

Comment: As a community moderator, one of my roles is to try to help users refine their questions to get better answers, faster. In its current form, this question is not attracting answers (3 days unanswered, two comments reporting that it's unclear), so I am recommending that you edit it to explain what specific feature or step you need help making in your game. You can of course ignore this suggestion, but it's likely to result in continuing to get no useful answers. The more information you add, the better your chance of getting the help you need.

Comment: The [Colorolo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1c11vTKPVKU) game reminds me a lot of Google Material Design, for which there's a free [Unity asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/google-material-design-47141) using UI Tween -- maybe by grabbing it and analyzing how it does things, you can get some inspiration for implementation patterns?

Comment: @DMGregory The speed at which you flagged my question is the most logical reason why nobody that may know what I am talking about avoided this all together. It also attracts down voters just because. All it takes is one and a user's inquiry is pretty much dead. I would like to see the statistics of questions flagged for closure getting answered and the flags removed simultaneously. For the years Ive been here, I have yet to honestly see that happen. It typically translates to one person's view regulating the community to his experience & understanding of a topic.

Comment: I think you may be confused. I have not flagged your question. (As a moderator, I can't flag a question for closure without instantly closing it, because of how the system works — and this question is still open) Your question has received zero down-votes to date. But you do have two comments from two different users saying more focus would help clarify this question. I'd recommend acting on that advice, as I think it will help you attract useful answers.